# Adapter update statement in oledb

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with retrieved data form ms access database. While updating using the adapter update statement, it shows Syntax error.

The following are the connection code in form load event and update button click event.

could you please let me know whats wrong in this?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\DESKTOP\VBATESTING\ADPE Project\Project Tables\ADPE_Table.accdb"
    inc = 0

    Dim Con As New OleDbConnection()
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Heidelberg"
    Con.ConnectionString = strConn

    Try
        Con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
    Adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)

    ds = New DataSet

    Adapter.Fill(ds, "testing")

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("testing").Rows.Count
    Label1.Text = "Total Records :" & MaxRows
    NavigateRecords()
End Sub


 Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter)

    ds.Tables("testing").Rows(inc).Item(5) = TextBox1.Text
    ds.Tables("testing").Rows(inc).Item(2) = TextBox2.Text
    ds.Tables("testing").Rows(inc).Item(3) = TextBox3.Text
    ds.Tables("testing").Rows(inc).Item(4) = TextBox4.Text
    Try
        Adapter.Update(ds, "testing")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Set the `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` properties of your command builder.  Before you ask, no.  You search the web to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

You have way too many commands in your Form.Load.

One

```
Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand
```

Two

```
Cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
```

Three

```
Adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
```

Every time you use the New keyword, you create another command.

If you are only dealing with a single table, you don't need a DataSet. The extra object adds extra weight and complicates the code a bit.

```
Private inc As Integer
Private Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Private MaxRows As Integer
Private dat As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\DESKTOP\VBATESTING\ADPE Project\Project Tables\ADPE_Table.accdb"
    inc = 0
    Using Con As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
        Using Cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Heidelberg;", Con)
            Adapter.SelectCommand = Cmd
            Try
                Adapter.Fill(dat)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    MaxRows = dat.Rows.Count
    Label1.Text = "Total Records :" & MaxRows
    NavigateRecords()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
    dat.Rows(inc).Item(5) = TextBox1.Text
    dat.Rows(inc).Item(2) = TextBox2.Text
    dat.Rows(inc).Item(3) = TextBox3.Text
    dat.Rows(inc).Item(4) = TextBox4.Text
    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter)
    'This will take care of any spaces that you have in column names.
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["
    cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    Try
        Adapter.Update(dat)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! yes, it works with this update. Stackoverflow's contribution to the programmers world is tremendous. Thank you. M D Shivaram